# How to copy a readonly object in c# and modify the copy

Tags: c#

I have an object defined as:

```
readonly List<object> Params;
```

I need to get the values stored in the list as integers but all the casting methods I have tried like `Convert` class, explicit typecasting using `(int)` give the following error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidCastException

I tried to print the elements and it gives me the integer value of the objects but copying the list keeps the `readonly` attribute and I am unable to use the value in my program.

Comment: Do you have integer values in this list, or you have strings which hold integers?

Comment: What is the object type of `Params`? What does the list hold

Comment: What are the inputs? What is the code you already tried? Let us know a bit more info ;)

Comment: I don't think `readonly` does what you think it does...  `readonly` ONLY means that you cannot set the value of Params (except from the constructor or field initializer, and then only once).  It doesn't stop you from adding or removing values from the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `readonly` has no effect at all on the values stored in the list. It applies only to the `List` object, but not to its content. So forget about it, nothing wrong here.

Instead, there MUST be a conversion problem with at least one of the values stored in `Params` (btw.: the exception clearly says that)...

You may use [`int.TryParse(...)`](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CEIQFjAC&url=http://www.dotnetperls.com/int-tryparse&ei=8S6wUp_ZA4fUtQayhYCwBw&usg=AFQjCNGNB5OJk2dXIoTaiAt8MaUg7IZwYA&bvm=bv.57967247,d.Yms) to find out which value it is.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Linq` to do this, for sample, add this namespace

```
using System.Linq;
```

And try to use the `Cast<T>` method to convert,

```
List<int> ints = Params.Cast<int>();
```

You also could use the `Select` method if you need to do something more specific, for sample:

```
List<int> ints = Params.Select(x => {

                                     // its a scope, and you can do it here...

                                     if (something)
                                        return (int) x;
                                     else if (other condition)
                                        return int.Parse(x.ToString());

                                      return x; // other custom conversions...

                                    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Params.Cast<int> may be more elegant ;-)

Comment: `Params.Cast<int>().ToList()` would be better, it can shortcut if the underlying object implements IEnumerable<int>

Comment: @dasheddot Not just more elegant, can be more efficient.

Comment: @BobVale Sure, but it doesn't seem the QA wants to micro-optimize. But of course you are right - anyways I was 3 seconds faster :)

Answer (score 1):

If the elements in the list are strings, use

```
int value = int.Parse((string)Params[i]);
```

If the elements int the list are ints, use

```
int value = (int)Params[i];
```